# The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have tried to build the demo in VS2019+NET Core 3.1.

https://github.com/PeterHimschoot/BlazorRevealed

The BlazorControlsDemo.Controls, BlazorControlsDemo.Shared were built ok.
But BlazorControlsDemo.Client is failed:

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var serviceProvider = new BrowserServiceProvider(services =>
            {
                // Add any custom services here
            });

            new BrowserRenderer(serviceProvider).AddComponent<App>("app"); // <------Error
        }
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BrowserServiceProvider**, **BrowserRenderer**. They have been obsolete for ages now.

This is probably an old app from the Middle Ages. Just throw away. A good source of learning and practicing Blazor can be  [found here](https://chrissainty.com/), with complete and updated samples.